# Proof of inequality problem from Spivak, ch 1, 16 b)

Tags: inequality

If $$4x^2+8xy+4y^2 \ge 0$$ it follows that $$4x^2+6xy+4y^2 \gt 0 $$ unless $x=0$ and $y=0$.

How can I prove that?

Comment: Did you mean to say: it follows that $4x^2+\color{red}{8}xy+4y^2>0$

Comment: No, I wrote it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the premise is uninformative because you *always* have
$$
0\leq (2x+2y)^2=4x^2+8xy+4y^2.
$$
Second, it is also unnecessary because you also *always* have
$$
4x^2+6xy+4y^2=(2x+3y/2)^2+7y^2/4\geq 0
$$
with equality iff $x=y=0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:$$4x^2+6xy+4y^2=x^2+3(x+y)^2+y^2\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:$$4x^2+6xy+4y^2 = 4\left(x^2+\dfrac{3}{2}xy+y^2\right)=4\left(\left(x+\dfrac{3}{4}y\right)^2+\dfrac{7}{16}y^2\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The way that I think of it is as follows. First, we need to recognise that

$$ 4x^2+6xy+4y^2=3(x+y)^2 + x^2 + y^2$$

Then, based on the stated assumption we know that:

$$ 4x^2+8xy+y^2=4(x+y)^2 \ge 0 $$
$$ (x+y)^2\ge0$$

$(x+y)^2 = 0$ when $x=-y$ or when $x=y=0$

For all other values $(x+y)^2\gt0$

Similarly, 
$$ x^2 + y^2 \ge 0$$
$x^2 + y^2 = 0$ where $x=y=0$

For all other values, $x^2+y^2\gt0$

Combining these two steps we find that where $x$ and $y\not=0$:
$$3(x+y)^2\ge0\; and\; x^2 + y^2 \gt0$$
$$\therefore\;3(x+y)^2+x^2+y^2\gt0$$
$$4x^2+6xy+4y^2\gt0$$

P.S. I'm just working through this chapter myself, so my understanding is pretty basic. I'm sure others have expressed this more elegantly, but hopefully my fumbling thought process will be helpful for other beginners.